# Diffusion coefficients of glucose in mammal tissues?

Tags: metabolism, tissue

Where can I find estimates/experimental measurements of the diffusion coefficient of glucose in mammal tissues? Specefically I mean the inter-cellular space. I'm not looking for a specific tissue, so some examples of values for some tissues, or a generic estimate, is enough for me.

And the same for lactate, although I presume it will be very similar.

Comment: [Something to start with!](http://optics.sgu.ru/_media/optics/staff/bashkatov/chapter-19.pdf) (see table 19.1)

Comment: This question cannot be answered as is. What do you mean by tissue ? Inter Cellular space ? Cytoplasm ? Nucleus ? Blood stream ? etc etc All of those media have very different diffusion properties.

Comment: @Xqua I mean extracellular glucose, inside a tissue, so it's in the inter cellular space. I edited the question.